# Use context for communication between components at different level

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js, react-context

I'm building the settings pages of my apps, in which we have a common `SettingsLayout` (parent component) which is rended for all the settings page. A particularity of this layout is that it contains an `ActionsBar`, in which the submit/save button for persisting the data lives.

However, the content of this `SettingsLayout` is different for each page, as every one of them has a different form and a different way to interact with it. For persisting the data to the backend, we use an Apollo Mutation, which is called in one of the child components, that's why there is no access to the `ActionsBar` save button.

For this implementation, I thought React Context was the most appropriated approach. At the beginning, I thought of using a Ref, which was updated with the submit handler function in each different render to be aware of the changes.

I've implemented a codesandbox with a very small and reduced app example to try to illustrate and clarify better what I try to implement.

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-tdd-y8tpj8?file=/src/App.tsx

Is there any caveat with this approach?

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

type State = {
  onSubmit?: React.MutableRefObject<() => void>;
};

type SettingsContextProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  value?: State;
};

type ContextType = State;

const SettingsContext = React.createContext<ContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const SettingsContextProvider: React.FC<SettingsContextProviderProps> = ({
  children
}) => {
  const onSubmit = React.useRef(() => {});

  return (
    <SettingsContext.Provider value={{ onSubmit }}>
      {children}
    </SettingsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useSettingsContext = (): ContextType => {
  const context = React.useContext(SettingsContext);

  if (typeof context === "undefined") {
    /*throw new Error(
      "useSettingsContext must be used within a SettingsContextProvider"
    );*/

    return {};
  }

  return context;
};

function ExampleForm() {
  const { onSubmit } = useSettingsContext();

  const [input1, setInput1] = React.useState("");
  const [input2, setInput2] = React.useState("");

  onSubmit.current = () => {
    console.log({ input1, input2 });
  };

  return (
    <div className="exampleForm">
      <input
        placeholder="Input 1"
        onChange={(event) => setInput1(event.target.value)}
      />

      <input
        placeholder="Input 2"
        onChange={(event) => setInput2(event.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function ActionsBar() {
  const { onSubmit } = useSettingsContext();

  return (
    <section className="actionsBar">
      <strong>SETTINGS</strong>

      <button onClick={() => onSubmit?.current()}>Save</button>
    </section>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SettingsContextProvider>
        <ActionsBar />

        <ExampleForm />
      </SettingsContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Another example of a pattern that would use this (or any better approach) would be the typical floating action button.

Answer (score 0):

The main caveat I see in this approach is that you change the whole submit function when you need only reaction to submit event. Event is the catch, I think.

Your approach works ok, but has no extension points, for cases such as validation etc.

So I propose to use EventEmitter in any form (better with types support) as a context value e.g. communication channel.

This is a fork of your codesandbox that illustrates this approach:
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-fog-qlrusj?file=/src/App.tsx